# Reasoning for "Illuminator" badge

Tags: discussion, reputation

I just realized that there is an "Illuminator" badge:

[image]

That really surprised and baffled me and ultimately lead to the following question:

- Isn't that already going in the direction of bad / misguided incentives and leaving the realm of sensible [gamifaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification)? I fear that this kind of badge can coerce people either into sinking a huge amount of time into this site. This is of course beneficial for the community, but could lead to neglection of "real-life" duties / tasks. Especially considering that if someone is striving for this badge, they will need multiple attempts given that the probability of coming across 500 questions that one can answer properly (score > 0) within 12 hours is rather low.

Given that only 24 members ever [received this badge on SO.SE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator) and none here on GameDev shows how improbable it is to get this badge. I however assume none of the current recipients specifically aimed for this badge as a concrete target but rather simply spent more or less 12 hours non-stop on the site.

So, after all this is most likely not a critical issue, but again it just baffled me and I would like to here what you think about it. Discuss!

Comment: To gain one "action" towards this badge you must edit and answer the same / one single question within 12 hours. Do this 500 times over however long you want and you get the badge. You don't need to edit and answer 500 questions within 12 hours.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator

Answer (score 3):

As Spartan says, the individual action you need to do to earn this badge is to edit *and answer* (within 12 hours) a question. Your answer has to have a non-zero score. You must repeat *that* 500 times.

You don't have to do all 500 edits within a 12 hour period.

Getting the badge isn't improbable, it just takes time, and many of the ways you could try to abuse/game the system for this badge will raise flags for moderators or sufficiently-high-rep users to deal with (excessive edits, review queues, et cetera).

Comment: Okay, that is indeed much more sensible. Thanks for the clarification to you and SpartanDonut. In retrospect, I should probably have realized that on my own: Doing those 500 edits + answers in 12h would mean that for each thread you would only have 1.44 minutes...that is without any breaks.